# C++ Problems with write array function

Tags: c++, arrays, file-writing

I'm trying to write a function that will write an array (2D) to file. This is the code below:

```
#ifndef WRITE_FUNCTIONS_H_
#define WRITE_FUNCTIONS_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

 void write_array(string name, int rows, int columns, double **array){

    ofstream output;
    output.open(name, ios::out);

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
            output<<array[r][c]<<",";
        }
        output<<endl;
    }

    output.close();

}

#endif
```

When I try to run it in this program here:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "write_functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    double **array = new double*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        array[i] = new double[10];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            array[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    string array_name="home/Plinth/Documents/Temp/array.txt";

    write_array(array_name, 10, 10, array);

    return(0);
}
```

It runs perfectly fine, without error or warning, but there is no file created. Did I write something improperly? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `ofstream output; output.open(name, ios::out);` Why don't people use the constructor? `ofstream output(name);`?

Comment: You should check that `output.is_open() == true`

Comment: Try `"/home/Plinth/Documents/Temp/array.txt"` instead of `"home/Plinth/Documents/Temp/array.txt"`, most likely you're trying to create a file in a directory which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aleph Dammit! I'll delete my question.

Comment: @Plinth Don't, just leave it here and accept the given answer.

Comment: Why do you have code in a header file?  You should place function implementations into source files (e.g. .cpp, .cxx).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It is. those are two separate files. I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Why are there include guards in a source file?  Normally, source files aren't labelled with a ".h" extension, and they don't have include guards.  I'm talking about the `write_functions.h` file that you posted, which has the implementation of a function in it.  This means that every file that includes the header file gets the implementation (and there will be multiple implementations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're likely writing in an unexpected directory.

Try to fully specify the path like `/home/...` (note the first '/') or just write it to a local file like `array.txt`.

Comment: Yeah, Aleph alerted me to that. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

When handling file streams, I prefer using this idiom to detect errors early.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("no_such_file.txt");

    if (!input) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file 'no_such_file.txt': " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // The file opened successfully, so carry on
}
```